# Import error is still there even when I have removed that import [React]. Any solution?

Tags: reactjs, importerror

Failed to compile.

./src/pages/newProduct/NewProduct.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in 'C:\Users\DELL\MERN STACK\ECOMMERCE\admin\src\pages\newProduct'

Comment: Hello, your question needs improving, very little information is given. 
Based on what you said, you most likely have an issue with `node_modules`. Did you install all required dependencies? Also did you install them in the right folder?

Comment: I checked the dependencies, there was a dependency missing. The issue has been resolved thank you.

Comment: Cool, you can close this question. Idk if it's possible unless I give an answer, so I'll do that too and you can select it as answer and close it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments:

> Hello, your question needs improving, very little information is given. Based on what you said, you most likely have an issue with node_modules. Did you install all required dependencies? Also did you install them in the right folder? –

Issue was that dependency was missing - as answered by the author.